# ios memory going up very fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, instruments

I have a pretty general question here.
What would you do in general to find who's taking your memory?

I have a video encoder, the setup is pretty complex, the `images` are into a controller and the encoder is in another and i'm asking for the `images` and get them through delegates which are sometimes going through many levels of controllers, and i'm also using some `dispatch_async` calls in the process. Images are snapshots of an `UIView` and processed with `CoreGraphics`, i'm retaining the final image and releasing it in the other controller after use. Everything works fine, the memory is around 25Mb constantly, but what happens is that after I finish the encoding the memory is going up very fast, in maximum a minute is going from 25Mb to 330Mb and is of course crashing. I tried to put logs and see if is still asking for images but doesn't seem to be any problem, the encoder stops as expected. The encoder is set to run in background.

One important thing is that if I try to find leaks (or allocations because leaks are not reporting anything with ARC) the app is crashing sooner, but not because of the memory. I suspect that I messed the dispatches somehow and because of some delays caused by instruments something is not available at a specified time. However I have troubles finding this too without logs. Can I see logs when i'm debugging with instruments?

Thanks for any info that will help.

Edit: I succeeded to run the instruments with the allocs without doing anything, seems the crash is not consistent. I saved the instruments report and you can see how's the memory going up, there's an alloc that is causing this and i think the question resumes to how to read it. The file is here http://ge.tt/1PF97Pj/v/0?c

Comment: Have a look at Console.app, which shows the logs for your system. You may not see your logs when running under instruments, but they go to Console.app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're "busy-waiting" on `adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData`, -- i.e. calling it over and over in a tight loop. This is, generally speaking, bad practice. The headers state that this property is Key-Value Observable, so you would be better off restructuring your code to listen for Key-Value change notifications in order to advance the overall process. Even worse, depending on how `AVAssetInputWriter` works (I'm not sure if it's run-loop based or not), the act of busy-waiting here may actually *prevent* the asset input writer from doing any real work, since the run loop may be effectively deadlocked waiting for work to be done that might not happen until you let the run loop continue.

Now you may be asking yourself: How is busy-waiting causing memory pressure? It's causing memory pressure because behind the scenes, `readyForMoreMediaData` is causing autoreleased objects to be allocated every time you call it. Because you busy-wait on this value, checking it over and over in a tight loop, it just allocates more and more objects, and they never get released, because the run loop never has a chance to pop the autorelease pool for you. (see below for more detail about what the allocations are really for) If you wanted to continue this (ill-advised) busy-waiting, you could mitigate your memory issue by doing something like this:

```
BOOL ready = NO;
do {
    @autoreleasepool {
        ready = adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData;
    }
} while (!ready);
```

This will cause any autoreleased objects created by `readyForMoreMediaData` to be released after each check.  But really, you would be much better served in the long run by restructuring this code to avoid busy-waiting. If you absolutely must busy-wait, at least do something like `usleep(500);` on each pass of the loop, so you're not thrashing the CPU *as* much. But don't busy-wait.

EDIT: I also see that you wanted to understand how to figure this out from Instruments. Let me try to explain. Starting from the file you posted, here's what I did:

I clicked on the Allocations row in the top pane
Then I selected the "Created & Still Living" option (because if the things were getting destroyed, we wouldn't be seeing heap growth.)
Next, I applied a time filter by Option-dragging a small range in the big "ramp" that you see.
At this point, the window looks like this:
[image: Instruments up to this point]

Here I see that we have tons of very similar 4K malloc'ed objects in the list. This is the smoking gun.
Now I select one of those, and expand the right pane of the window to show me a stack trace.
At this point, the window looks like this:
[image]

In the right panel we see the stack trace where that object is being created, and we see that it's being alloced way down in `AVAssetInputWriter`, but the first function below (visually above) the last frame in your code is `-[AVAssetWriterInput isReadForMoreMediaData]`. The `autorelease` in the backtrace there is a hint that this is related to autoreleased objects, and sitting in a tight loop like that, the standard autorelease mechanism never gets a chance to run (i.e. pop the current pool).

My conclusion from this stack is that something in `-[AVAssetWriterInput isReadForMoreMediaData]`, (probably the `_helper` function in the next stack frame) does a `[[foo retain] autorelease]` before returning its result. The autorelease mechanism needs to keep track of all the things that have been autoreleased until the autorelease pool is popped/drained. In order to keep track those, it needs to allocate space for its "list of things waiting to be autoreleased". That's my guess as to why these are malloc blocks and not autoreleased objects. (i.e. there aren't any *objects* being allocated, but rather just space to keep track of all the autorelease operations that have happened since the pool was pushed -- of which there are MANY because you're checking this property in a tight loop.)

That's how I diagnosed the issue. Hopefully that will help you in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that with kvo i get notified only once about the change, maybe is not changing after that? The main thread is indeed blocked by this tight loop, so what i do now is to ask for the next image with a delay. This has few problems, the cpu has many spikes which doesn't look good to me, the time will be longer, and the UI is blocked in waves. I have an object spinning to show the progress. With dispatch_async were no waves, just moving slower. The memory problem was from my dyspatch_async combination but how to use them properly is for another discussion.

Comment: The header says very explicitly "This property is key value observable. Observers should not assume that they will be notified of changes on a specific thread." So if you're not getting notified, then I would bet it's not changing. If you're expecting the notifications to arrive on the main thread though, you will need to marshal them over yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, the memory issue is fixed if i remove the `dispatch_async` calls, however now my UI is blocked which is not good at all. It should be a way to combine all this so i do not block it. Here is my code

```
- (void) image:(CGImageRef)cgimage atFrameTime:(CMTime)frameTime {
//NSLog(@"> ExporterController image");
NSLog(@"ExporterController image atFrameTime %lli", frameTime.value);

if (!self.isInBackground && frameTime.value % 20 == 0) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        //logo.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimage];
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%%", frameCount/**100/self.videoMaximumFrames*/];
    });
}

if (cgimage == nil || prepareForCancel) {
    NSLog(@"FINALIZE THE VIDEO PREMATURELY cgimage == nil or prepareForCancel is YES");
    [self finalizeVideo];
    [logo stop];
    return;
}

// Add the image to the video file
//dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),^{
    NSLog(@"ExporterController buffer");
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:cgimage andSize:videoSize];
    NSLog(@"ExporterController buffer ok");
    BOOL append_ok = NO;
    int j = 0;

    while (!append_ok && j < 30) {

        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
            //printf("appending framecount %d, %lld %d\n", frameCount, frameTime.value, frameTime.timescale);
            append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
            if (buffer) CVBufferRelease(buffer);
            while (!adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {}
        }
        else {
            printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
            //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
            while(!adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {}
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (!append_ok) {
        printf("error appending image %d times %d\n", frameCount, j);
    }
NSLog(@"ExporterController cgimage alive");
    CGImageRelease(cgimage);
NSLog(@"ExporterController cgimage released");
//});


frameCount++;
if (frameCount > 100) {
    NSLog(@"FINALIZING VIDEO");
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [self finalizeVideo];
    //});
}
else {
    NSLog(@"ExporterController prepare for next one");
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),^{
        NSLog(@"ExporterController requesting next image");
        [self.slideshowDelegate requestImageForFrameTime:CMTimeMake (frameCount, (int32_t)kRecordingFPS)];
    //});
}
```

}

Comment: To answer further to my problem, i succeeded to unblock my UI with wrapping the requestImageForFrameTime in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{. Previously i had too many dispatchers that made this one not to work.